# How do you beat level 5 hard mode on lineum?

Tags: lineum

I just need to know where to move my line in order to pass it. I've been on the same level forever

Comment: Can you add details of what you tried? Screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, of course next move is the upper red tile:

[image]